# a button that catches doesnt redirect browser when requested

Tags: javascript

I have some js that catches when a button is clicked, it works fine but I want to redirect the browser after div is hidden but it doesnt work? Any ideas?

The js code is :

```
    $(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.output_message').text('Logging job...'); 

      var form = $(this);
      $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        method: form.attr('method'),
        data: form.serialize(),
        success: function(result) {
          if (result == 'success') {
            $('.output_message').text('Message Sent!');
            form[0].reset();
            $('#5box').hide();
            window.location.replace("index.php");
          } else {
            $('.output_message').text('Error Sending email!');
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: post your html!

Comment: Can you add a console.log(result); in the ajax callback and post the result?

Comment: Add the full code as a snippet

Comment: do you get the "message sent" alert?

Comment: @Zagonine it is not true. the syntax for redirect is correct. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-in-javascript-jquery) for more details